# Invalid Template Error when integrating custom webhook trigger with Microsoft Flow

Tags: webhooks, asp.net-webhooks, power-automate

I am trying to create custom webhook trigger in Microsoft Flow.
I have created one sample application where I have implemented webhook service. The application calls the hooks when events occur.

I tried integrating my webhook server with Microsoft Flow by referring to [link](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/customapi-webhooks/#creating-webhook-triggers-from-the-ui)

I created swagger and adding trigger from flow UI but I end-up getting the below error

```
"InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for trigger 'When_File_get_created_in_project_share' at line '1' and column '4703': 'The template language function 'ListCallbackUrl' is not supported by triggers of type 'ApiConnection'.'."
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi. I am getting the same error. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Can you share the code of your webhook service?

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same error when I tried creating a custom webhook. The testing was successful but while creating the flow , had the same error.